# How to make \\MachineName\SharedFolder equivalent to \\MachineName\c$\SharedFolder on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

Let's say I've a folder **c:\SharedFolder** which I want to share with **EVERYONE**. I'm able to share it. So entering **\\MachineName** in windows explorer shows this folder. And everyone can access it via **\\MachineName\SharedFolder**.

But **\\MachineName\c$\SharedFolder** isn't accessible via explorer. I'm assuming that's probably because **\\MachineName\c$** isn't shared.

Is that assumption right?

Obviously I don't want to share c$. So I'm wondering if it is possible still to expose \\MachineName\c$\SharedFolder?

OS: Windows 7, Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to `\\MachineName\SharedFolder` because you set the correct sharing permission AND file permission.

You can't access to `\\MachineName\c$` just because c$ is shared with acces only for admin. So every folder inside it can't be reached.
If you want everyone to access to your c$, you have to share it for everyone. You correctly said this is a very bad idea..

For a folder to be correctly shared, you have to:
1 - setup the correct rights on the share
2 - setup the correct rights on files and folders
Often we set every rights for everybody on the share (never do that for c$), and we configure the correct rights for files and folders.

Comment: so in short answer to 2nd question is no. Right?

Comment: You can expose c$ to everyone only if you "open" the share to everyone. So the answer is... depend. But no, you musn't. Ever.